# How to get the number of inputs from the user dynamically?

Tags: python

I am the getting multiple inputs from the user which i can't measure, how can i read all the inputs dynamically.

For example

a,b = input(), input()

we can get only two inputs but i want to take multiple inputs at a time without knowing the count of inputs we are getting.

My input is coming as

```
3
11
1 2 -1 4 0 5 -3 8 7 0 10
10
1 2 -1 4 0 5 -3 8 7 10
5
1 2 3 4 5
.
.
etc
```

each line each input.

Comment: Take space separated/delimited inputs

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27955697/input-multiple-files-in-python-using-via-the-command-line

Comment: Why don't you use a while loop and exit once a certain cirteria is met (e.g. when the input is "empty")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> for your input format

```
lines = []
while True:
  line = list(map(int,input().split()))
  if line:
    lines.append(line)
  else:
    break
print(lines)
```

input:

```
3
11
1 2 -1 4 0 5 -3 8 7 0 10
10
1 2 -1 4 0 5 -3 8 7 10
5
1 2 3 4 5
```

output

```
[[3], 
 [11], 
 [1, 2, -1, 4, 0, 5, -3, 8, 7, 0, 10], 
 [10], 
 [1, 2, -1, 4, 0, 5, -3, 8, 7, 10],
 [5], 
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

> For Single Line input

```
inputnumbers=list(map(int,input("Input:").split()))
print("Output",inputnumbers)
print("input[3]",inputnumbers[3])
```

Output

```
Input: 1 2 3 4 5
Output [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
input[3] 4
```

> For multiLine

```
lines = []
while True:
  line = input()
  if line:
    lines.append(line)
  else:
    break
print(lines)
```

Input:

```
1 2 3 4 5
asdf asdf asdf
1234
```

Output:

```
['1 2 3 4 5', 'asdf asdf asdf', '1234']
```

Comment: Would be better to give the variable name other than `input` since you may want to use `input()` later in the program

Comment: This will work when all the inputs are  coming in a single string format, but here every input is different.

Comment: welcome!! if you got your answer please accept and upvote my answer!!

Comment: sorry i don't have access to upvote. I am new to Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible without having some way of denoting when to stop reading from standard input.  E.g. Python needs to know when to stop blocking waiting for input from standard in and to proceed to executing the rest of your code.

You could, as some have suggested, take all inputs on a single line with delimiters such as commas or whitespace.

Alternately, you could use a special character such as a newline or a line with just whitespace (or some other magic string) as the cue to python to stop reading from standard in, e.g.

```
inputs = []
while True:
    next_input = input()
    if not next_input.strip():
        break
    inputs.append(next_input)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read from `input()` in a loop, and append the returned value to a list `values`.

When the user hits Ctrl+D, an [End of File](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/End_of_File) will be sent to Python, raising an `EOFError`. When the user hits Ctrl+C it sends a `KeyboardInterrupt`. Both we can use to signal that we are done reading numbers.

```
values = []
while True:
    try:
        values.append(input())
    except (EOFError, KeyboardInterrupt):
        break

print(values)
```

Catching EOFs in this way has the advantage that we can also redirect other streams or files into our loop and the end of the redirected file will be recognised: with a file `inputs` like

```
1
2
3
hello
```

you can do

```
cat inputs | python test.py
```

and get

```
['1', '2', '3', 'hello']
```